# Can I ensure that python base class method is always called

Tags: python

I have a python abstract base class as follows:

```
class Node(object):
    """
    All concrete node classes should inherit from this
    """
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.inputs = dict()

    def add_input(self, key, value=None, d=None):
        self.inputs[key] = (d, value)

    def bind_input(self):
        print "Binding inputs"

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        pass
```

Now, various derived classes will inherit from this node class and override the `run` method. It is always the case that `bind_input()` must be the first thing that should be called in the `run` method. Currently, for all derived classes the developer has to make sure to first call `self.bind_input()`. This is not a huge problem per se but out of curiosity is it possible to ensure this somehow from the base class itself that `bind_input` is called before executing the child object's `run`?

Comment: Does the method have to be abstract? `def run(self): self.bind_input()`  Then all subclasses call base.run() first, which is a more intuitive standard.

Comment: Yeah, as all child classes must have class specific implementation of `run`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual object-oriented approach is this:

```
def run(self):
    self.bind_input()
    return self.do_run()

@abstractmethod
def do_run(self):
    pass # override this method
```

Have your subclasses override the inner method, instead of the outer one.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're talking so much about metaclasses. There's nothing in the question to suggest that the questioner was thinking of writing a metaclass to solve this. (While they are using the ABCMeta metaclass, that's mandatory for an abstract base class.)

Comment: True! Removed the unnecessary text

Comment: That is awesome. I am ashamed I did not think of this. Thanks.

Comment: Never be ashamed! Next time, this will be your first approach =)